# Can I include data-type safety for the parameters of function in PHP?

Tags: php

I am developing a complete object oriented based Web application in PHP 5. So I need it to be type-safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php), but make sure you're aware of its limitations.